# Symfony and Doctrine : how to trace SQL callers (sql backtrace)?

Tags: doctrine, symfony5

With Wordpress I use the Query Monitor plugin to debug sites, it's very similar to Symfony WDT. What I found very interesting is the plugin can trace the caller of every SQL query :
[image]
Is there any similar tool for Symfony WDT ? I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153161/doctrine2-in-symfony2-how-can-i-see-which-object-call-leads-into-a-query) but It's very old (I'm using Symfony 5) and is a bit far from what I'm looking for

Comment: Have you tried the answers to the question you linked... or this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470738/how-to-get-doctrine-to-log-queries-in-symfony2

Comment: The question I linked is a bit far from what I'm looking for, I'd like to see callers without altering my current code. The question you linked is completely different : it's how to log all SQL queries, nothing about callers !

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)
in `doctrine.yaml` I've added this :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...    
        profiling_collect_backtrace: true
```

New link added in Query Metrics :
[image]

Doc is here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/latest/configuration.html

Found the solution here : [Symfony Profiler Query Stack Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631856/symfony-profiler-query-stack-trace)